# Android how is resource id number converted?

Tags: android

For example I have some number like:

```
Strig num = resources.getResourceName(2130903218);
```

and I get back:

```
Unable to find resource ID #0x7f0300b2
```

how I get from `2130903218 -> #0x7f0300b2`. Which format is that? Can I get from `#0x7f0300b2 -> 2130903218`

I am writing some docs and I need to know how is this converted.

Comment: Um, why would you *ever* have `resources.getResourceName(2130903218)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing of special, when the exception is thrown the ID is print as Hex string

```
1013 public void More ...getValue(int id, TypedValue outValue, boolean resolveRefs)
1014            throws NotFoundException {
1015        boolean found = mAssets.getResourceValue(id, 0, outValue, resolveRefs);
1016        if (found) {
1017            return;
1018        }
1019        throw new NotFoundException("Resource ID #0x"
1020                                    + Integer.toHexString(id));
1021 }
```

So simply using `Integer.toHexString` ([grep code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/content/res/Resources.java#Resources.getValue%28int%2Candroid.util.TypedValue%2Cboolean%29))

Answer (score 2):

0x7f0300b2 = 2130903218, getResourceName will return the name of resources. 
e.g:

```
<resources>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string></resources>
```

and `resources.getResourceName(R.string.hello_world)` will return a single string of the form "package:string/hello_world".You should see the [reference doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getResourceName%28int%29).